# showing total scores with localStorage - Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'd like to display scores and total scores in a basic clicking game. Every time the user clicks, the scores add 1 , and totalscores adds the total and the 1 generated in scores.

Every time the user starts the game the total score is showing and then it just keeps adding the numbers showed in scores

I think this works in the first round -> the scores are the same as total scores in the board and when i click start the totalScores are showing instead of going back to 0.

But when i start clicking the element the total scores don't add what I have stored they just follow along the number of scores.

How can I store the total and just add the score ?

```
 the click function

      score++;
      scoreBoard.textContent = score;

      localStorage.setItem("totalscore", score);

      total.textContent = "total " + localStorage.getItem("totalscore");

the start function
         score = 0;
         scoreBoard.textContent = "0";
         total.textContent = "total " + localStorage.getItem("totalscore");
```

Comment: when you are setting the `totalscore` you are just setting the `score`, instead try scoring
`totalscore + score`. Get the totalscore first from the localstorage, add score into it and then store it back.

Comment: Keep in mind, that `localStorage` is storing strings, so a cast to Number is needed also.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right in assuiming that this is your Javascript code:

```js
 click = () => {

      score++;
      scoreBoard.textContent = score;

      localStorage.setItem("totalscore", score);

      total.textContent = "total " + localStorage.getItem("totalscore");
}

start = () => {
         score = 0;
         scoreBoard.textContent = "0";
         total.textContent = "total " + localStorage.getItem("totalscore");
}
```

Then you should do the following:

```js
 click = () => {
      score++;
      scoreBoard.textContent = score;
      localStorage.totalscore = score;
      total.textContent = "total " + localStorage.totalscore;
}

start = () => {
      score = 0;
      scoreBoard.textContent = "0";
      total.textContent = "total " + localStorage.totalscore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage set the items as string

Use `Number(localStorage.getItem('totalScore'))` to convert string to number

Answer (score 0):

```
the click function

      score++;
      scoreBoard.textContent = score;
      var currentTotalScore = new Number(localStorage.getItem("totalScore") || 0);
      localStorage.setItem("totalscore", currentTotalScore + score);

      total.textContent = "total " + localStorage.getItem("totalscore");

the start function
         score = 0;
         scoreBoard.textContent = "0";
         total.textContent = "total " + localStorage.getItem("totalscore");
```